# Generating changeset and adding it to JAR with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I'm generating a git diff changeset using the `maven-changelog-plugin`. This plugin runs when I run `mvn site` or `mvn changeset:changeset` and outputs the changeset file into `target/site/changeset.html` and `/target/changeset.xml`. I would like to include this generated file in the jar that is built when I run `mvn clean install`.

How can I include this generated file in the JAR? I've tried using the `build-helper-maven-plugin` to add an artifact or to add a source, but it seems that the changeset is created as the last step or isn't discoverable.

My most recent attempt:

```xml
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <id>changelog-report</id>
            <configuration>
              <type>range</type>
              <range>30</range>
            </configuration>
            <reports>
              <report>changelog</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>add-changelog-to-artifact</id>
        <activation>
            <file><exists>target/site/changelog.html</exists></file>
        </activation>
        <build>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.3.0</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>add-source</id>
                  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <sources>
                      <source>target/site/changelog.html</source>
                    </sources>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Comment: Looking at the plugin docs I couldn't see which phase `changelog:changelog` was bound to by default, but you can add plugin configuration, as you have for the `build-helper-maven-plugin` which will run changelog in an earlier phase.

Comment: @tgdavies I did try adding a phase to the `build-helper` plugin, but when used in the `<reporting> block it always runs last. I tried moving the plugin to the <build> block with an earlier phase, and it still did not work. 
Even using `mvn site install`, which builds the reports first, does not work because the `add-changelog` plugin does not find the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the `maven-changelog-plugin` was that it always ran at a step later than the build step where it needed to be. I ended up using the `gitlog-maven-plugin` instead, which allowed me to change the phase at which it executed